# How to find and replace dynamic IDs from JSON server data and update with the matching IDs in the DOM

Tags: jquery

It's already few weeks I have been trying to find different solution but can't get it working correctly. Hired few from fiverr but really it's a waste of time there.
Here is what I am looking for:
I have json data update_ingame.json in the server. The json data has html chars. I will need to update json data on front end that has matching dynamic IDs.

client site js file is using node js (socket) so it's a real time updates.

update_ingame.json

```
{"update_ingame":"
 <div id=\"bt_1001\">2<\/div>
 <div id=\"bt_1052\">3<\/div>
 <div id=\"bt_1011\">4<\/div>"
}
```

HTML DOM in the front end

```
 <div id="bt_1001">1.4</div>
 <div id="bt_1052">2.5</div>
 <div id="bt_1011">3</div>"
```

It's clearly visible it has same ID on both but the value within the div in json is changed which is I need update and replace corresponding DOM elements in the front. The IDs are unique and dynamic which need updates only that are present in the page.

client.js Here is one of what I tried

```
var update_ingame = data.update_ingame; //data from node
var parsedIngame  = jQuery.parseHTML(update_ingame);

var bt_id = jQuery(parsedIngame).attr("id").replace("bt_", "");
console.log(bt_id);
jQuery(bt_id).html(jQuery(parsedIngame[1]).find(bt_id).html());
```

Of course, it is working perfectly if I update the entire page content but my requirement is that those entire page update doesn't work when the users has logged in session, that's the reason why I will need to update each individual unique IDs.

I hope someone help me. I will be happy to buy coffee for anyone shed light on this.

Comment: Can you change server side JSON to be `{"update_ingame":{"bt_1001":"2",{...}}}`? It would be much faster and easier. E.g. `$('#' + jsonKey).text(jsonValue)`. Also `jQuery(bt_id)` should contain `#`: `jQuery('#' + bt_id)`

Comment: The data in your update_ingame.json file isn't valid JSON btw

Comment: @Justinas Thanks for the suggestion. I'd definitely try this when I learn more about it. Right now I am just using json_encode($htmArrays) php code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Justinas suggested if you can change the Json Result that would be best.  That is example 3.   Example 1 is if the property of your results "update_ingame" is truly suppose to be one long string.  If it's suppose to be an array of strings then that's example 2.

HTML:

```
<div id="bt_1001">1.4</div>
<div id="bt_1052">2.5</div>
<div id="bt_1011">3</div>
<button id="Example1">Example 1</button>
<button id="Example2">Example 2</button>
<button id="Example3">Example 3</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var data1 = {
  "update_ingame": "<div id=\"bt_1001\">2<\/div><div id=\"bt_1052\">3<\/div><div id=\"bt_1011\">4<\/div>"
};
var data2 = {
  "update_ingame": [
    "<div id=\"bt_1001\">5<\/div>",
    "<div id=\"bt_1052\">6<\/div>",
    "<div id=\"bt_1011\">7<\/div>"
  ]
};
var data3 = {
  "update_ingame": [{
      "id": "bt_1001",
      "value": "8"
    },
    {
      "id": "bt_1052",
      "value": "9"
    },
    {
      "id": "bt_1011",
      "value": "10"
    },
  ]
};


$("#Example1").on("click",function(){
    var myData = data1.update_ingame.replace(/div><div/g,"div>-*-<div").split("-*-");
  var myIdValues = [];

  $.each(myData, function(i,v){
        var pair = {};  

    var myArray = v.split(">");
    pair.value = myArray[1].substring(0,1);
    pair.id = myArray[0].substring(myArray[0].search("\"")+1, myArray[0].length-1);

    myIdValues.push(pair);
  });

  $.each(myIdValues, function(i,v){
    $("#"+ v.id).text(v.value);

  })


});

$("#Example2").on("click", function(){
var myData = data2.update_ingame;
var myIdValues = [];
  $.each(myData, function(i,v){
        var pair = {};  

    var myArray = v.split(">");
    pair.value = myArray[1].substring(0,1);
    pair.id = myArray[0].substring(myArray[0].search("\"")+1, myArray[0].length-1);

    myIdValues.push(pair);
  });

  $.each(myIdValues, function(i,v){
    $("#"+ v.id).text(v.value);

  })

});

$("#Example3").on("click", function(){
    var myData = data3.update_ingame;

  $.each(myData, function(i,v){
    $("#"+ v.id).text(v.value);
    console.log(v)
  })
})
```

Edit:

Now that we know that the value for `update_ingame` is an HTML string we can adjust the Fiddle sample.  I've updated the fiddle with the data you provided in your comment.

HTML:

```
<div id="bt_1135310966">1.4</div>
<div id="bt_1135310974">2.5</div>
<div id="bt_1135310975">3</div>
<div id="bt_1135310976">4</div>
<button id="Example1">Example 1</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var data1 = {
  "update_ingame": "<div id=\"bt_1135310966\">4</div><div id=\"bt_1135310974\">2.25</div><div id=\"bt_1135310975\">1.57</div><div id=\"bt_1135310976\">2.2</div>"
};


$("#Example1").on("click",function(){
    var myData = $.parseHTML(data1.update_ingame);
  $.each(myData, function(i,v){
    var value = $(v).text();
    var id = $(v).attr("id");  
    $("#"+ id).text(value);
  });
});
```

[New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tyddlywink/7mbcuL4s/)

Comment: Appreciate for taking time to respond. My problem is just as given in example 1. It's a single long string. I did tested your code. It's strangely inserting random values which is actually not matching with the one in json.

Comment: Actually data1.update_ingame console output plain html string like this: <div id="bt_1135310966">4</div><div id="bt_1135310974">2.25</div><div id="bt_1135310975">1.57</div><div id="bt_1135310976">2.2</div>

Comment: Now that we know the correct format for `update_ingame` I've updated the fiddle and my answer.

Comment: @Matt I would still be looking at refactoring your data. It much more efficient on **many** levels to just pass data. Don't pass HTML, pass data in both directions.

Comment: @Tyddlywink  It's working!  Thanks so much.. I have one question before marking the answer.. Sometimes I will have 2 same ID in the DOM.. I'd like to update the same value on both. Right now, it seems it update only one ID. The other ID doesn't get the value update.

Comment: @Tyddlywink  Just realized that having 2 elements with the same ID is not valid html according to the W3C specification. I'd like to add class with same class name as in ID in the DOM  but the json file will remain same i.e just ID. So in DOM it will look like <div class="bt_1001" id="bt_1001">2.5</div>.  Can you suggest on this? s

Comment: This `$("#"+ id).text(value);` to this `$("."+ id).text(value);`

Comment: @Tyddlywink Thanks mate! All resolved for now. If you are comfortable please share your PayPal mail in the chat section or message(not sure haven't used), I'd buy you a coffee as promised in the question.

Comment: @JonP i'd like to but don't have enough expertise to package into json string as Justinas suggested above. Appreciate your suggestion. Would like to try your suggestion in the later days. For now all i did is json_encode($HtmArrays)

Comment: @Matt Your thanks is more than enough.  I would suggest you get more comfortable with Json to do what Justinas, JonP and I suggest.  It's cleaner and the best way to do it.   Happy Coding